# Error with MSys2 toolchain when using ghcup to install Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, msys2

My Haskell installation suddenly decided to break itself, so I uninstalled it. When I tried to install again with ghcup, I got the following error when trying to install the MSys2 toolchain:

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
Exec: Error executing command curl.exe with arguments '-o
C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\\msys2-x86_64-latest.sfx.exe
https://repo.msys2.org/distrib/msys2-x86_64-latest.sfx.exe'
At line:170 char:11
+           throw ('Exec: Error executing command {0} with arguments '' ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Exec: Error exe...latest.sfx.exe':String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Exec: Error executing command curl.exe with arguments '-o C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\T
   emp\\msys2-x86_64-latest.sfx.exe https://repo.msys2.org/distrib/msys2-x86_64-latest.sfx.exe'
```

I've installed Haskell before without getting this error before. What could this possibly mean? Thank you!

Comment: One ghc related issue was reported here https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/10837.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NOTE: This has been fixed! All I had to do was open up MSys2 and type in `echo "ssl-no-revoke" > ~/_curlrc`. This worked like a charm!